# kivy - Why does the video player show error?

Tags: python, kivy

In py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''                
<Test_win>:
    VideoPlayer:
        source: 'test.mp4'
        eof: 'stop'
''')

class Test_win(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class VidApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test_win()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app =VidApp()
    app.run()
```

The video player runs successfully but until the end of the video, I can't play it for another time (it crashes). It crashes also when I click on the stop button.

Before that, I had removed the Gstreamer for the 'share'folder and replace it by ffpyplayer (type `set KIVY_VIDEO=ffpyplayer` in prompt).

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jared\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-02-21_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.1.0
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4509'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 400'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 20.19.15.4509'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 4.1.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file test.png
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture test.mp4
```

Can anybody help me to fix it?